# Is a singleton appropriate for this design?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

My model is implemented, and I'm working on a view.

I have class named Helper that is part of my controller.  The intent of the Helper class is to contain the "master copy" of the model.  Other classes will call Helper methods to request their own copies of the model (whole or specific parts of it).  Helper is also the only class that should be allowed to make changes to the model.

The view I'm working on contains a JPanel called DrawingPanel.  The paint() method of DrawingPanel is overridden such that it retrieves the model from Helper before it paints itself.

Is implementing the Helper class as a singleton the best way to accomplish this, or is there a better/simpler/more elegant way to accomplish my goal?

I guess I should also know ahead of time if my implementation of Helper as a singleton will need to be thread safe or not.  The gui is designed in Swing.

Comment: Really, is there any reason to *prevent* the creation of a second instance, when it takes less work to just *not try to create one*?  An instance passed to your objects on construction would accomplish the same goal as a singleton, without the artificial limitations and hidden dependencies inevitably caused by implementation of the Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for whether a capital-S "Singleton" is appropriate...ask yourself this...

> Is a second instance *certain to cause the death of my program*?

(I do mean "certain" and "death".  Not just "likely"...and not just some confusion about which instance is the "official" one.  If the program will crash, implode, open a wormhole, set fire to your dog, etc *entirely due to the existence of a second instance*, the answer is "yes".  If you're not sure, assume "no" til you have sound evidence otherwise.)

If the answer is "yes", then you *may* have a valid case for using Singleton.  If not, then you're misusing it, and there's a better solution:
**Just don't create a second instance.**

There are several misguided reasons for using Singleton:

- "I want to be able to use my object without passing it all around the app."  Guess what?  What you have is a glorified global variable.  And it's even more evil when it's hiding in the bowels of some class than it is sitting out for all the world to see.  **If you want to use a global, then use a freaking global.**  Don't hide it behind a getter and think people won't notice.
- "I only need one of these."  See above.  **You only need one?  Only *create* one.**  Whether you need it right now or not, do you have good reason to *force* there to ever be exactly one?  What if you want another in the future?  Not only have you made it a pain to create another one, but you've probably built your class in such a way that only one can exist -- and will have lots of "design" to undo.
- "It's convenient being able to say `MySingleton.getInstance()`."  Yeah, til you start caring about tests.  See, every time you call `MySingleton.getInstance()`, you've added one more assumption that that is the only type that that object can ever be.  If you ever start messing with unit testing, your tests will be pretty much useless, because they all depend on the behavior of that one instance -- and even the sequence in which the tests run.  Even a global isn't as bad for testability, and it kinda sucks.  (Also, see "...without passing it all around the app" above.)

The solution to the singleton problem is generally **dependency injection**.  Big words, but very *very* simple premise; the non-frameworky version is basically, "That external stuff the object will need to do its job?  Pass it to the constructor."  There are DI container libraries/packages that can allegedly simplify this, but it all just amounts to *telling* the object what to use rather than making it go and find stuff for itself.  So you **pass your one instance to the object that needs it**, and it never has to say `MySingleton.`anything -- or even *care* whether that object is a singleton or not.

Comment: So are you saying I should consider just creating one global instance of my model class, and pass that to the paint method every time it is invoked?  I hope I've understood that correctly...  It seems far more elegant than what I was considering and I'd like to explore that as a solution, I just don't want to find halfway through that I've misinterpreted and am trying something that just isn't going to work.

Comment: It doesn't particularly *have* to be a global instance; that's kinda a last resort.  Ideally, you'll want to keep the object's scope and visibility as small as possible for sanity's sake.  (It's better to try to make sure the code only depends on either the object it lives in, or the args it's passed.)  Passing it to the draw function is pretty much what i am suggesting, though -- or, if that's not possible, to the object's constructor.

Comment: Well, I have a Dashboard class that creates an instance of the DrawingPanel class.  So I could declare a public static instance of Helper in Dashboard.  I'm going to start taking it in this direction and see how it goes.

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding the static instance if you can, really.  "Static" is just how Java says "global".  If the Dashboard is what owns the DrawingPanel, and the DrawingPanel and Helper are closely related, you might consider making the Helper an *instance* member of a Dashboard -- or possibly even of the DrawingPanel, if they're that closely related and you can extend that class.  Although, if the two are *so* closely related that you always use one with the other...

Comment: I ended up making Helper an instance member of Dashboard. I wasn't able to re-write DrawingPanel.Paint() to take a copy of the model as a parameter as it's an override of the Paint() method from it's super (JPanel) and must maintain the same signature.  Instead I added DrawingPanel.getModel(Model model). Anywhere within Dashboard where I would have done DrawingPanel.Paint(), I just do DrawingPanel.getModel(Helper.getModel()) first.  It seems to be working OK. I think I need to learn to use DI effectively to overcome this problem in future projects, however.

Comment: TLDR: Don't look for things (:

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to have one instance of the `Helper` class, then a singleton is a way to enforce that. If your helper class contains any non-global state, then a singleton is probably not appropriate. It is also possible to have multiple instances of helper that share a single master model.

Be cautious with singletons though, because your code can end up quickly full of

```
MySingleton.getInstance()
```

This is difficult to mock out for testing as well (see http://jeffastorey.blogspot.com/2009/08/spring-managed-singletons-for.html). If you are using a dependency injection framework, I would recommend injecting the singleton into the relevant classes (or using something like the registry pattern http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html to lookup the singleton object so you can still mock it out for testing).

My answer here is just some guidance, the real answer is like so many software questions is "it depends."

Comment: If I were to have multiple instances of Helper that share a single master model, would I do that simply by declaring the instance variable that holds the model as static within the Helper class?

Comment: Typically I would inject that using a dependency injection framework (such as Spring), but you could make it static as well.

Comment: Thanks for you comments on DI, it spurred me on to a bunch of reading that made me realize I need to learn to use that pattern effectively.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, it looks like you would want to make it a singleton.  Also, yes you will need to make it thread-safe if you are using multiple threads.  One more thing, rename it, "Helper" is a horrible name for a class.  Name it what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no, you should avoid using singletons that provide "global access to a service".

See the link and an except below.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx

> What ends up happening is that the dependencies in your design are
>   hidden inside the code, and not visible by examining the interfaces of
>   your classes and methods.

Comment: Just because a blog post says "Singletons are Evil" doesn't convert it in a golden rule for every project.

Answer (score -1):

> Is implementing the Helper class as a singleton the best way to
>   accomplish this, or is there a better/simpler/more elegant way to
>   accomplish my goal?

If your intent is to have a single `Helper` to be used by all your app, then yes singleton is the way to go.

> I guess I should also know ahead of time if my implementation of
>   Helper as a singleton will need to be thread safe or not.

And if it will be accessed by multiple threads, yes it must be thread-safe